# Meteor Publish all collections only for specified user (admin)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

How to publish all meteor `collections` only to user with `{role: "admin"}`? The meteor `autopublish` package gives db access to all clients. Is there a way to use `autopublish` package with some access restrictions or a function simmilar with access parameters?

(as a bonus it would be nice to have `insecure` package with the same restrictions, but it's not neccessary).

Comment: Read through the tutorials (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) it looks like `autopublish` and `insecure` are designed to do exactly the opposite of what you want and you need to implement your own methods, like that described in the tutorial I just linked, if you want specific or secure behaviour

Answer (score 1):

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  // pseudo code
  if (user && user.role == "admin") {
    return [
      Col1.find(),
      Col2.find(),
      Col3.find(),
      ...
    ]
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

This is an anonymous publication, (null) you don't need to subscribe to it.. it will be automatically published to the client..

Comment: Is there a difference between `Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId)` and `Meteor.user()`?

Comment: yes, there is.. you can't use Meteor.user() in publish functions.. 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user